# Is it possible to use both rtx and amd cards at the same time?

Tags: gpu

I bought a amd card recently but keep reading about how blender works faster with rtx cards. So can I sometime in the future buy a rtx card and combine it with the amd card or is there no way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to mix different kinds of cards from different hardware architectures.

Comment: Yes, ive read its not a good idea, too bad, but is it also not posible? or blender has an option to do it?

Comment: It is possible, The options are there, but those who have tried it report inconsistencies in the rendered images.